# User class for future inheritance in other programs involving user activity

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented

I am making an user class which I could inherit and use in the future.
(recently started learning Python and OOP)

```
import mysql.connector as mycon
class user:
    host = "localhost"
    user = "root"
    password = "pass"
    database = "USERS"
    table = "UserData"

    def __init__(self,firstName,lastName,userName,email):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.userName = userName
        self.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName
        self.email = email

    @classmethod
    def login(cls,userName,password):
        db = mycon.connect(host = cls.host,user = cls.user,password = cls.password,database = cls.database)
        cursor = db.cursor()
        r=cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {} WHERE UserName = '{}';".format(cls.table,userName))
        userInfo = cursor.fetchone()
        if(userInfo!=None):
            if(userInfo[2]==password):
                print("Login Successful")
                return cls(userInfo[0],userInfo[1],userInfo[3],userInfo[4])
            else:
                print("INVALID PASSWORD",password,userInfo[2])
        else:
            print("USER DOES NOT EXIST")
        db.close()

    @classmethod
    def register(cls,firstName,lastName,password,userName,email):
        db = mycon.connect(host = cls.host,user = cls.user,password = cls.password,database = cls.database)
        cursor = db.cursor()
        r=cursor.execute("Insert into {} values('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}');".format(cls.table,firstName,lastName,password,userName,email))
        db.commit()
        db.close()
```

with a table UserData with description

[image]

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. Not claiming being new to DB programming, better don your asbestos. (Nah. [Everything *should* be meant constructive](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/conduct), even if not praise.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most important things to take care of when writing a database application is to prevent unwanted access. This means that you always want to make sure that there is no user (and the programmer, i.e. you should be included in that) can supply an input that can escape the query and e.g. delete your whole database. This attack vector is called SQL injection and is very common. [Avoiding it is relatively easy, thankfully](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_where.asp), although you cannot do it for the table name:

```
@classmethod
def login(cls, user_name, password):
    db = mycon.connect(host=cls.host, user=cls.user, password=cls.password,
                       database=cls.database)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    query = f"SELECT firstName, lastName, password, UserName, email FROM {cls.table} WHERE UserName = %s;"
    r = cursor.execute(query, (user_name,))
    user_info = cursor.fetchone()
    if user_info is not None:
        if user_info[2] == password:
            print("Login Successful")
            return cls(user_info[0],user_info[1],user_info[3],user_info[4])
        else:
            print(f"INVALID PASSWORD {password} {user_info[2]}")
    else:
        print("USER DOES NOT EXIST")
    db.close()
```

Note that I followed Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which recommends using `lower_case` for variables and functions, spaces after commas and around `=` when using it as an assignment, but no space around the `=` when using it for keyword arguments.

Comparisons to `None` should always be done with `is` or `is not` and `if` conditions don't require parenthesis, since it is a keyword.

I also explicitly named the column names (they might be called differently, judging by `UserName`, so you would have to fix that), to ensure that you can change the table structure, as long as these names stay the same.

And I used an [`f-string`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) for easy formatting in case of an invalid password. Note that in this case you do reveal the actual password (I guess this is just for testing, just make sure you don't forget to remove that information later). In a similar vein, you should not store passwords in plaintext. Hash them with a good hashing algorithm and ideally add a salt.

You could also use the [`mysql.cursor.MySQLCursorNamedTuple`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursornamedtuple.html) cursor, so you can say `user_info.password` instead of `user_info[2]`. Just use `cursor = db.cursor(named_tuple=True)`.

You should do yourself a favor and add a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to every method you write, to explain what the method does, what its arguments are and what it returns.

Comment: How to prevent revealing the password

Comment: @VISHALAGRAWAL Just don't print the password that was input and the real password, `print("INVALID PASSWORD")`.

Comment: Oh forgot to remove those thanks for help man